# 4 bit 4:1 mux structural modelling in verilog using veriwave

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am designing a structural model for a 4 bit 4:1 multiplexer.
My verilog code is shown below.Eda playground is throwing a segmentation fault while executing the code.But no issue when it is executed using other simulators.The log is shown below.

design.sv: L1: error: syntax error, unexpected INPUT

design.sv: L7: error: 'a' not declared

design.sv: L7: error: 'b' not declared

design.sv: L7: error: 'c' not declared

design.sv: L7: error: 'd' not declared

design.sv: L7: error: 'sel' not declared

design.sv: L8: error: 'sel' not declared

design.sv: L9: error: 'out' not declared

design.sv: L9: error: 'a' not declared

design.sv: L10: error: 'out' not declared

design.sv: L10: error: 'b' not declared

design.sv: L11: error: 'out' not declared

design.sv: L11: error: 'c' not declared

design.sv: L12: error: 'out' not declared

design.sv: L12: error: 'd' not declared

./run.sh: line 4:    14 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) veriwell design.sv testbench.sv

```
module mux_4to1_case ( input [3:0] a,                 
                       input [3:0] b,                 
                       input [3:0] c,                 
                       input [3:0] d,                 
                       input [1:0] sel,               
                       output reg [3:0] out);  
  always @ (a or b or c or d or sel) begin
      case (sel)
         2'b00 : out <= a;
         2'b01 : out <= b;
         2'b10 : out <= c;
         2'b11 : out <= d;
      endcase
   end
endmodule
```

Verilog Test Bench

```
    module tb_4to1_mux;
    
      reg [3:0] a;
      reg [3:0] b;
      reg [3:0] c;
      reg [3:0] d;
      wire [3:0] out;
      reg [1:0] sel;
      integer i;
    
    
      mux_4to1_case  mux0 (   .a (a),
                           .b (b),
                           .c (c),
                           .d (d),
                           .sel (sel),
                           .out (out));
    
    
      initial begin
    
        $monitor ("[%0t] sel=0x%0h a=0x%0h b=0x%0h c=0x%0h d=0x%0h out=0x%0h", $time, sel, a, b, c, d, out);
    
    
        sel <= 0;
        a <= $random;
        b <= $random;
        c <= $random;
        d <= $random;
    
    
        for (i = 1; i < 4; i=i+1) begin
          #5 sel <= i;
        end
    
    
        #5 $finish;
      end
        initial begin
        $dumpvars;
        $dumpfile("sth.vcd");
      end
    endmodule
```

When the code is executed the following segmentation fault occurs
[Logs.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TmFH.png)

Comment: Why is your file `.sv` if it's Verilog? Is it ran as SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module header and port definitions in ANSI style which is legal since IEEE std 1364-2001.

EDAplayground has VeriWell 2.8.7 which only supports the 1995 version of the Verilog standard (IEEE std 1364-1995). The 1995 standard supports what is now called as non-ANSI style header. [VeriWell 3 on github](https://github.com/balanx/veriwell) mentions it supports some 2001 features.

You can convert your code from ANSI to non-ANSI (shown bellow) or change simulators. EDAplayground has a selection of simulators. Icarus is the most actively maintained free simulator. Aldec Riviera is a commercial simulator that is currently free to use on EDAplayground.

I'd recommend changing simulators unless you are explicitly required follow the IEEE1364-1995 standard. Modern simulators have moved to IEEE1800 SystemVerilog standard which is backward comparable with IEEE1364.

---

ANSI style header: (IEEE1364-2001 and later)

```
module mux_4to1_case ( input [3:0] a,
                       input [3:0] b,
                       input [3:0] c,
                       input [3:0] d,
                       input [1:0] sel,
                       output reg [3:0] out);
```

Non-ANSI style header: (IEEE1364-1995 and later)

```
module mux_4to1_case (a,b,c,d,sel,out);
  input [3:0] a;
  input [3:0] b;
  input [3:0] c;
  input [3:0] d;
  input [1:0] sel;
  output [3:0] out;
  reg [3:0] out;
```

---

Other notes:

- `always @ (a or b or c or d or sel)` works with IEEE1364-1995 but been simplified to `always @*` with IEEE1364-2001 and latter. SystemVerilog IEEE1800 enhanced it further with `always_comb`/`always_latch` (neither with `@`) for some synthesis requirements checking in simulations.
- Non-blocking assignments (`<=`) should be used to assign flip-flops and intended latches. Combilational logic should use blocking assignments (`=`). Your 4:1 mux represents combilational logic therefore needs blocking assignments. Incorrect usage of blocking/non-blocking can lead to unexpected simulation behavior and RTL vs syntheses mismatches.